# How to use if statement with pd.Series object in pandas agg function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to aggregate a dataset in which one of the columns contains some URLs. Consider the following dataset

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
                   "Website": ["https://www.auctionbid.com",
                               "https://www.google.com",
                               "https://www.awesomeauctions.net",
                               "https://www.awesomeauctions.net",
                               "http://www.auctionnoitcua.com"
                              ]
                 })
```

I would like to perform the following analysis:

```
(
df
.groupby("ID")
.agg({"Website": lambda x: 
      "; ".join([site for site in x if x.str.contains("auction")])
    })
)
```

This results in a `ValueError` stating that the truth value of a Series is ambiguous. The accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) states that `if` can implicitly convert the operands to `bool`, and suggests using "bitwise" operators.

My question, then, is how do I implement the equivalent of `&` and `|` for `if`?

Comment: `x` is a Series (for each ID you have a different Series in agg). pandas doesn't know whether you want to join if all the items contain that word, or if any of them would suffice. I also don't know how you want to join but if you want to join only the websites which contain the string auction, then instead of a condition on x, just change the comprehension to `site for site in x if 'auction' in site`

Comment: @ayhan Thank you for this explanation, it definitely helps explain what was going wrong. I was interpreting the procedure as looping through each value of `x` and selecting only those where "auction" was found. I now understand what's actually happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas builtin `pd.Series.str.contains` and `pd.Series.str.cat` methods to explicitly accomplish this:

```
join_func = lambda x: x[x.str.contains("auction")].str.cat(sep="; ")
df.groupby("ID").agg({"Website": join_func})
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it will result in a series inside the lambda function and not a single value. Pandas will complain.

Comment: Right, the join was missing, just added it.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because I think it's a little bit clearer what the function is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison cannot work because x is the whole series and not just the item you are processing. This works:

```
df.groupby("ID")['Website'].agg(lambda x: "; ".join([site for site in x.values if "auction" in site]))
```